# 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to run a migration for my Django project, but I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'
```

I when I ran make migrations on all my apps, I didn't get any errors. It's only when I try to actually migrate. I can't tell from the traceback information which model is creating the problem, or even which app. I've looked at my models, and I don't see anything that pops out at me.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, sessions, case_manager, file_manager, auth, contenttypes, tasks, people_and_property
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying file_manager.0006_auto_20160109_1536...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 467, in alter_field
    return self._alter_many_to_many(model, old_field, new_field, strict)
  File "/home/mint/Python_Projects/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 274, in _alter_many_to_many
    old_field.remote_field.through._meta.get_field(old_field.m2m_reverse_field_name()),
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'
```

How do I figure out which model is the problem? What should I look for?

Comment: you get this error after changes in some model?

Comment: I've made a couple minor changes. I've actually tried to go back and change them to the way they were, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm not doing anything fancy, literally just ManytoMany fields with a related_name.

Comment: Can you show the full field definition?

Comment: I think what happened was that I had two models both with manytomany fields that pointed to each other. So the Note model had a related_cases manytomany field pointing to the Case model, and the Case model had a related_notes field pointing to the Note model. I removed one of the manytomany fields, deleted the migrations files, reran makemigrations, and then ran migrate without an error.

Answer (score 11):

You have to make sure that the model you are creating the 'ManyToManyField' is already created in the database.

You can do that by adding as a dependency the migration where the model is created to your migration in which you alter the field:

Scenario 1: You alter the field to 'ManyToManyField' with a model from other app

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
      ..........
      ('[app]', '__first__'),
    ]

    operations = [
       .........
    ]
```

Scenario 2: You create a 'ManyToManyField' and the model you are referring to is in the same file:

```
 class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
      ..........
    ]

    operations = [
       .........
       # Make sure the model you are making the reference with is  before the ManyToManyField
       migrations.CreateModel(...) ,
       migrations.AlterField/CreateField(...)

    ]
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, but I don’t know if for the same reasons. Luckily I don’t have any important data in the system, so I just changed the migration as follows – **but note that this deletes all data in these columns!**

Before:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='authors',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='resources_authored', to='api.Person'),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='editors',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='resources_edited', to='api.Person'),
    ),
]
```

After:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='authors',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='editors',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='authors',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='resources_authored', to='api.Person'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='resource',
        name='editors',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, related_name='resources_edited', to='api.Person'),
    ),
]
```

While the altering failed for mysterious reasons, removing and recreating the fields worked.

Comment: Wouldn't that delete all the data that may have been stored in those fields though ?

Comment: @Brachamul, aye. That’s what I mean by “Luckily I don’t have any important data in the system, so I just changed the migration as follows.” I’ll edit and make that clearer.

Comment: the following answers by @Sagar and jsep are much more useful

Comment: @TauPan Upvoted. I weakly doubt that it was a dependency issue in my case, but it’s been too long to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason might be your `api.Person` model migrations might not have run before the one in which it is referenced(in your example it is `file_manager.0006_auto_20160109_1536`). So make sure `api.Person` migrations are run before, by adding them in the dependencies of `file_manager.0006_auto_20160109_1536`.

Comment: This is what caused and solved it for me. I added the dependency to the migration like so :`dependencies = [ ..., ('api', '__first__'), ]`.
After that, the AlterField worked.

Comment: @Brachamul maybe you should accept this answer, then?

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question, so I can't accept the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to rename a table which was referenced with a many to many fields.
I resolved it this way:
- dumped the manytomany relationship data into a file
- removed the manytomany field and migrated
- renamed the table and migrated
- added the manytomany field back and migrated and loaded the relationships from the dump

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but the way that I fixed it, is the following steps:
Nota: You will lose data from that ManyToManyField

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate app_name --fake
```

Don't forget the --fake

After that.
I removed (or just comment the line) the ManyToMany field, and then makemigrations app_name, migrate app_name.

At this step you have this column from your database cleared, what you need to do now is to re add the ManyToManyField, so when you makemigrations app_name & migrate app_name again.
You server can run perfectly

It's not the best, but it worked for me.
hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

My problem came with changing a field from a choices field to a manytomanyfield.

If you do this and keep the same name, then you'll have issues.

I followed Denis Drescher:

Basically go through your migration files and check what django is doing with these fields.

If django is doing migrations.AlterField for the field which was a choices field and is now a manytomanyfield, change it to 
migrations.RemoveField and then Migrations.AddField

Answer (score 0):

I had no meaningful data as yet, so I deleted the database(db.sqlite3) and all migrations(0001,0002 etc)

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if you renamed model-related attributes or anthing related to the model in the admin before you drop the db.
Actually it worked for me.